# PHP regular expression to extract html values

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-match-all

I want to extract values from the code below.

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="file_pdf"><a href="javascript:downloadFile('1628')">note1</a></div></td>
      <td class="textright">110 KB</td>
      <td class="textright">106</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="file_pdf"><a href="javascript:downloadFile('1629')">note2.pdf</a></div></td>
      <td class="textright">44 KB</td>
      <td class="textright">104</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

I want to extract 'note1', 'note2' strings and 1628 and 1629 numbers.

i treid

```
preg_match_all('~(\'\)\">(.*?)<\/a>)~', $getinside, $matches);
```

but its result is not what I am looking for..

is there any simple RegEx to extract them? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work for you:

```
preg_match_all("~downloadFile\('(\d+)'\)\">([^<]*)</a>~", $getinside, $matches);
```

**Remember:** If your html is very large/complex and you also need to parse more other things from there, then regex is not a better option to do this.